# How to make a view appear through animation when a button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to the coding. I am making an application where i need to make a view appear when a button is clicked and the view should appear as if it has come from the button itself. And on clicking the button again the view should go back to button (animated).

I have animations like flip, curl but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

//Here animationButton is the name of the button
// Here aView  is a view

aView.view.center=animationButton.center;

Now,scale the view to a small scale as shown so that when you make it bib,it gets shown as if it is coming from the button itself.

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(aView.view.transform, 0.01, 0.01);

aView.view.transform = trans;   // do it instantly, no animation

[self.view addSubview:aView.view];

// now return the view to normal dimension, animating this transformation
```

//Now with the help of animation ,scale the view to some large extent by animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                                  aView.view.transform =   CGAffineTransformScale(aView.view.transform, 70.0, 70.0);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example. Set `showView:` as the button's action.

```
- (IBAction)showView:(UIButton *)sender {
    // Create a view with the size and position of the tapped button
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sender.frame];
    // Set a color on the view
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    // Add the new view to the main view. The new view will be displayed over any other views
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    // Animate the change of the new view's frame. We use the bounds of the main view.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.6 animations:^{
        view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }];
}
```

**Complete solution:**

First create properties for the view and the button. How you initialize these is up to you.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *aView;
...
@synthesize button = _button;
@synthesize aView = _aView;
```

Then create a method that animates a view between two frames and will remove the view from its superview at the end of the animation if asked to.

```
- (void)animateView:(UIView *)view 
           fromRect:(CGRect)from 
             toRect:(CGRect)to 
       inParentView:(UIView *)parent 
     removeWhenDone:(BOOL)remove 
{
    if (!remove) {
        [parent addSubview:view];
    }
    view.frame = from;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.6 animations:^{
        view.frame = to;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (remove) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then create a boolean property that indicates if the view is shown, and implement a custom setter for the property.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL viewShown;
...
@synthesize viewShown = _viewShown;

- (void)setViewShown:(BOOL)viewShown
{
    _viewShown = viewShown;
    if (_viewShown) {
        // Insert your own toRect
        [self animateView:self.aView fromRect:self.button.frame toRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) inParentView:self.view removeWhenDone:NO];
    } else {
        [self animateView:self.aView fromRect:self.aView.frame toRect:self.button.frame inParentView:self.view removeWhenDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Finally, in the button's action you flip the `viewShown` property.

```
- (IBAction)showView:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.viewShown = !self.viewShown;
}
```