# How to make specific li's under a button appear when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

First off just want to mention I'm very new to coding and I know my code isn't the most efficient, I'm just experimenting. Now to the question!

I have an EJS file that talks to a NodeJS proxy, which sends it JSON data to manipulate (hope I said that right). The code below is working fine for me, the only problem that I am having is that when I click on one button it unhides all the li's, instead of just the li's under the button I clicked. It's very hard to assign classes and then write JavaScript code for each class generated, because I don't know how many buttons there will be in the first place.

I currently have:

Javascript (jQuery) Code

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('li').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

HTML/EJS Code

```
<% for (i = 0; i < sortedStackName.length; i++) { %>
    <% if (sortedStackName[i] == sortedStackName[i + 1]) { %>
    <% } else { %>
    <button class="btn btn-primary space" id="<%= %>"><%= sortedStackName[i] %></button>
    <% data3.forEach(function (provider) { %>
    <% if (provider['stack_name'] == sortedStackName[i]) { %>
    <a href="#"><li class="hide"><%= provider['service_name'] %></li></a>
    <% }}); %>
```

Some posts I've read that haven't worked:

[jQuery display nested ul on click of div in parent li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111900/jquery-display-nested-ul-on-click-of-div-in-parent-li)

[how to make text appear when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132055/how-to-make-text-appear-when-a-button-is-clicked)

[How to make a view appear through animation when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784474/how-to-make-a-view-appear-through-animation-when-a-button-is-clicked)

[Trying to make a div appear when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853121/trying-to-make-a-div-appear-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of `<a>` tags is variable, I think placing them in a `<div>` and then toggling class for that `div` is a cleaner solution, and you can use Ashkan's suggestion there as well. So your EJS will look like:

```
<div class="hide">
<% data3.forEach(function (provider) { %>
<% if (provider['stack_name'] == sortedStackName[i]) { %>
<a href="#"><li><%= provider['service_name'] %></li></a>
<% }}); %>
</div>
```

And in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('div').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: This worked great! This allowed me to display all the <a> tags instead of just one! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `next()` function with `a` selector

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('button').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('a').toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `closest()` function with `li` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click'),function(){
     $(this).closest('li').addClass('hide');
  });
});
```